# Independence of a random variable jargon

Tags: random-variable, independence

Just a bit confused about whenever "Independent" random variable is used in probability/stats videos/books.

When we say an "Independent" random variable, are we referring to a random variable standalone or in relation to another random variable?

E.g.:

Let's say there is a Random variable X that maps the outcome of a dice roll to the real number i.e
Sample space: {1,2,3,4,5,6}
Random variable X:{1,2,3,4,5,6} --> (1,2,3,4,5,6) on real number line.

Can we say that the Random variable X is an independent random variable? as the outcomes of the experiment don't depend on each other. i.e getting a 6 is not dependent on getting a 4 or 3. (might be confusing this with iid)

Or when we talk about the independence of a random variable it is in relation to another random variable within the same sample space.

Let's say there is another random variable Y within the sample space where
Random variable Y :{2,4,6} --> (0), {1,3,5} --> (1) on a real number line

Now random variables X and Y are dependent random variables as P(X and Y) != P(X).P(Y). So, random variable X is not an independent random variable?

Apologies, if this is naive. Just not able to close this out even after spending a lot of time.

Comment: What definition(s) of independence are you familiar with?  Referring to one of them, if it is in fact a correct one, ought to resolve your question.  BTW, you might find [these posts here on CV](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=independen*+random+variable+definition+answers%3A1) to be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Independence always refers to more than one random variable. A single random variable should not be called independent. What you later write about $X$ and $Y$ is correct, however what you earlier wrtite about $X$ alone is not appropriate.

"Can we say that the Random variable X is an independent random variable? as the outcomes of the experiment don't depend on each other. i.e getting a 6 is not dependent on getting a 4 or 3." If you're talking about a single experiment, these can't be independent, as if you're getting a 6, you know that it isn't a 4 or a 3. Note also that this would be a statement not about $X$ on its own, but rather about the *two* random variables "indicator of 6" and "indicator of 3 or 4"- statements about dependence or independence are always about the relation between two or more RVs. (There is also (in-)dependence of sets such as $\{6\}$ and $\{3,4\}$ given a certain distribution, but this also always refers to two or more sets, and is in fact equivalent to independence of their indicator variables.)

If you mean that the result of $X$ in one experiment does not depend on the result in another experiment, you are actually making a statement about two different experiments modelled better by random variables $X_1$ and $X_2$, which have the same distribution (namely the distribution of your $X$ you had in mind originally) and are independent, hence "i.i.d." (as you suspected).

Comment: Thanks a lot for this! Really helps.

Comment: However, to take a better example. Let's suppose you have a deck of 6 cards(hearts) numbered from 1-6 and let there be an experiment of picking 2 cards one after the other but without replacement (similar to hypergeometric dist). Also, let's declare a random var Q such that Q{if 6 appears in second pick} -->1,  {else} -->0. Now, in this case, can I comment on the independence of random var Q? Clearly, having 6 in the second pick is dependent on whether we got that in the first place or not. Might be confusing the independence of a random variable with that of events.

Comment: @DDG As said already, (in-)dependence is always defined in relation to something else, so we can only comment on the independence of your Q of another random variable that needs to be specified. This is not different with sets/events. If you want to talk about the first and second pick, define $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ for the two picks, then you can say they are dependent for the given reason. (A similar case can be made with events.)

Comment: Technically, a single random variable *is* independent (because it vacuously fulfills all requirements of the definition).  Most people would likely misunderstand a strict use of this language, though!  Your last example begins to expose what might be a key technical issue: in order to talk about random variables being independent, *they must be defined on the same probability space.* This requires additional work in the two-experiment setting, where initially the $X_i$ might have been conceived of as defined on *different* probability spaces.